# How to print the name of checkboxes as they are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm making a task management tool and my app needs the capability of creating repeating tasks, so I'm trying to emulate Google Calendar's "repeating event" menu. This  one:

[image]

As you can see, when you check the boxes for the days of the week you want, the "Summary" field updates automatically with the days you have selected. How would I achieve this using AngularJS or JQuery?

The rest of the "Summary" options I did using `ng-if`, like this:

```
<div ng-if="recurrence_type === 'Weekly'">
    <div ng-if="recurrence_pattern === '1' && !recurrence_frequency && !recurrence_end">
        <p class="form-control-static"><b>Weekly</b></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="recurrence_pattern > '1' && !recurrence_frequency && !recurrence_end">
        <p class="form-control-static"><b>Every {{recurrence_pattern}} weeks</b></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="recurrence_pattern === '1' && recurrence_frequency && !recurrence_end">
        <p class="form-control-static"><b>Weekly, {{recurrence_frequency}} times</b></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="recurrence_pattern > '1' && recurrence_frequency && !recurrence_end">
        <p class="form-control-static"><b>Every {{recurrence_pattern}} weeks,
                                        {{recurrence_frequency}} times</b></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="recurrence_pattern === '1' && !recurrence_frequency && recurrence_end">
        <p class="form-control-static"><b>Weekly, until {{recurrence_end}}</b></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="recurrence_pattern > '1' && !recurrence_frequency && recurrence_end">
        <p class="form-control-static"><b>Every {{recurrence_pattern}} weeks, until
                                        {{recurrence_end}}</b></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where:

- `recurrence_pattern` is the number of weeks;
- `recurrence_frequency` is the number of occurrences;
- `recurrence_end` is the end date.

I mean, I could do it like I've been doing so far, using `ng-if`, but I would have to make a `ng-if` for every single combination of checkboxes and I'd be here all day. I'm betting there's an easier way.

This is my code for the checkboxes:

```
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Repeat on:</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="monday" title="Monday" value="Monday"> M
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" title="Tuesday" value="Tuesday"> T
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="wednesday" title="Wednesday" value="Wednesday"> W
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="thursday" title="Thursday" value="Thursday"> T
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="friday" title="Friday" value="Friday"> F
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="saturday" title="Saturday" value="Saturday"> S
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="sunday" title="Sunday" value="Sunday"> S
</label>
```

Again, the technologies I'm using is **JavaScript with AngularJS**, but I also have **JQuery** available since I'm using **Bootstrap 3**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery DOM selector `:checked`, but you should not. Because it's not really the "angular way" to do it.

What you want is something like this :

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = [{
      value: 'test1'
  }, {
      value: 'test2'
  }, {
      value: 'test3'
  }];
  
  $scope.result = function() {
    return $scope.values.filter(function(el) { return el.checked; }).map(function(el) { return el.value; }).join(', ');  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="value in values"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="value.checked">{{ value.value }}</div>
  
    <div>
      {{ result() }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution first since you provided an Angular solution. And it works. However, I can't seem to make it work with the `.checkbox-inline` Bootstrap class, to make it look like in the Google menu that I showed in the OP.

Comment: Okay, I managed to make it work like I intended. Thank you for giving me an answer in the "Angular way".

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through all checked checkboxes using `$("input:checked").each()` and then you get its value using `.val()`

```js
var answer = $("#SelectedAnswer").val();
$("input:checked").each(function () {
  var id = $(this).val();
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Repeat on:</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="monday" title="Monday" value="Monday" checked> M
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" title="Tuesday" value="Tuesday"> T
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="wednesday" title="Wednesday" value="Wednesday" checked> W
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="thursday" title="Thursday" value="Thursday"> T
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="friday" title="Friday" value="Friday" checked> F
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="saturday" title="Saturday" value="Saturday"> S
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="sunday" title="Sunday" value="Sunday"> S
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was a good suggestion but I ended up picking the angular answer.

Answer (score 1):

On click of checkbox you can get title of that checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="monday" title="Monday" value="Monday">

$scope.summary = "";
$("input:checked").each(function () {
  var title = $(this).attr("title");
  $scope.summary+= title;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at below code. It uses jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkbox-inline input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var selectedDays = "";
    var tempArray = []
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
      var name = $(this).val();
      tempArray.push(name);
    });
    selectedDays = tempArray.join(",");

    $(".summary").text(selectedDays);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Repeat on:</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="monday" title="Monday" value="Monday">M
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" title="Tuesday" value="Tuesday">T
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="wednesday" title="Wednesday" value="Wednesday">W
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="thursday" title="Thursday" value="Thursday">T
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="friday" title="Friday" value="Friday">F
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="saturday" title="Saturday" value="Saturday">S
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="sunday" title="Sunday" value="Sunday">S
</label>
<br/>
<br/>Summary:
<div class="summary"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer also worked great but the answer using Angular suited my needs the best.

Answer (score 1):

Click on checkbox you can get title of that checkbox.

```
  //in Controller
    $scope.CheckBoxes = [{
        value: 'CheckBox1'
    }, {        
        value: 'CheckBox2'
    }, {        
        value: 'CheckBox3'
    }];

    $scope.result = function () {
        return $scope.CheckBoxes.filter(function (el) { return el.checked;        }).map(function (el) { return el.value; }).join(', ');
    }


   // in View
  <div ng-repeat="value in CheckBoxes"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="value.checked">{{ value.value }}</div>
<div>
    {{ result() }}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if you missed it but @Magus had already given an answer identical to yours. Regardless, thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about replacing your checkboxes with a bootstrap multiselect? http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: This wasn't what I had in mind but thank you for your suggestion!